# For Experience cloud users, "Chatter isn't enabled or the user doesn't have Chatter access"

Tags: chatter, administration, experience-cloud

I'm trying to add Partner Experience cloud users to Collaboration groups but I get an error :

[image: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id]

The user's page says :

[image: Chatter isn't enabled or the user doesn't have Chatter access.]

It works perfectly with internal users, and my collaboration group access type is *private with customers*.

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_enable.htm&type=5) if the chatter access were granted through profiles I'd have a *Enable chatter* permission added in profiles, which I don't, neither in profiles nor in permission sets.

In setup / Chatter settings, everything is enabled so Chatter should be available for Community users right ?

Querying the ChatterSettings metadata api returns
[image: IsEnabled=true]

Any idea what I could do to enable it for experience cloud users ?

Comment: Do you have 'Enable Chatter permission' enabled(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_pbr_profiles.htm&type=5)?  Also check if chatter feed is enabled for that object, Set Up-->Chatter--> Feed Tracking

 
Search for the  object which is not showing on community.

 
Enable chatter feed for the object.

Comment: Hi Vinay, as I wrote in my question I don't have 'Enable Chatter' permission. Also there's no object where I could enable Feed tracking since the question is about Collaboration groups, not SObject feeds. Thanks however for your suggestions.